# Cassandra Geolocation, to index or not to index?

Tags: database, database-design, cassandra

My goal is to be able to write a query such that I can find all of the rows in a table between a certain radius of a lat and long.

So a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE lat > someVariableMinLat AND 
    lat < someVariableMaxLat AND
    lng > someVariableMinLng AND lng < someVariableMaxLng;
```

along those lines.

Now, my thought is of course these should be an index, and I just wanted to confirm that, and related reading or info would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query requires `ALLOW FILTERING` to run, assuming you've set **lat** and **lng** as secondary indices.

Since you're interested in related readings and information, I would gladly shere my little knowledge with you. let me start with *Allow Filtering*. You've created a rather complex query that *(1)* uses **<** and **>** instead of **=** *(2)* on more than one non-primary-key column.

What *Allow Filtering* does is that it will query a database first, and then it applies **some** part of your conditions on it. Therefore, it's far from efficient if performance is your concern.

Speaking of performance, it's important to note that a column that tends to have more distinct values is not a good candidate to be set as a secondary index. You may find out more about this topic [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useWhenIndex.html).

How would I do that?

I'm not sure about your requirements. But you could consider using [Geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash). Geohash is the encoded form of both longitude and latitude. It can get pretty precise as well. By using geohash strings, you can play a tradeoff game between the length of your geohash in characters and their precision *(the lengthier the string, the more pricise they become)*. Perhaps you may set the geohash as your index column which implies that the lengthier the geohash, the more distinct values the column would have. You may even consider setting it as the primary key to take the performace to a higher level.

*Or maybe, you could set two primary keys. One, to keep short geohash, and another one to keep the longer hash for the same location if you want different level of precision :)*

Comment: I really like the idea of introducing a gehash. But you should be careful choosing the right hash. Otherwise your data will get unbalanced

Comment: I think a geohash is going to be a good call, it doesn't really need to be terribly accurate, basically I want users to be able to see messages within 5 miles, 10 miles, etc.

Thank you @Kamyar, appreciate the post! If you have any further reading I can do, please point me in the right direction!